# Getting my re.findall to accept urls with a # symbol

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, url

Right now I have the line of code in python:

```
 urls = re.findall("(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-?=%.]+",str(field))
```

This searches if a keyword is in a url, however it doesn't parse urls which include a # correctly. An example link I am trying parse is

https://partalert.net/product.html?v=51421546#asin=B08KH7RL89&price=&smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&tag=partalert-21&timestamp=00%3A17+UTC+%281.3.2021%29&title=Gigabyte+GeForce+RTX+3080+VISION+OC+10GB+Graphics+Card&tld=.co.uk

However the parsing excludes the hashtag and everything after it:

https://partalert.net/product.html?v=51421546

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, i needed to add a few symbols to the character classes, here is the working regex: "(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?[\w/-?=%.#&+]+.[\w/-?=%.#&+]+"